# Lync does not start on OSX Yosemite (keeps rebooting)

Tags: macos, operating-system, osx-yosemite, lync

Since I updated my Mac to OSX Yosemite, **I can't log in to Microsoft Lync** (14.0.9).
The program keeps trying to connect, then connects for a second and disconnects back. This doing in an infinite loop.

Changing the language on my computer to "English" resolves the problem. *(Similar with this solution, but only the first steps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/baliles/archive/2014/09/23/lync-for-mac-osx-yosemite-sign-in-fails-repeatedly.aspx)*
But since my computer's language is Dutch (Nederlands), it has to work as well!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has released a fix for this now, described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/baliles/archive/2014/09/23/lync-for-mac-osx-yosemite-sign-in-fails-repeatedly.aspx) and downloadable [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36517).

This fixed the issue for me, no reboot or language changes needed.

Comment: The update (version 14.10.10) of Lync seems to resolves this issue. @jptsetme 's fix; might works since it downloads a file called _lync_14.0.10_141024.dmg_

Answer (score 5):

For me i was already on English US. I did the followings:-

1. So i changed it to another language.
2. Reboot
3. Changed back the language to English
4. Reboot

and it is working now

Comment: Correct, but I need Lync to work when my OS language is Dutch (so not English)

Comment: This worked for me without restarting. I added English UK as primary, applied, removed English UK, applied, Restarted Lync and it signed right in. I know this doesn't help our Dutch friend above, but hopefully it saves someone from double reboots!